# croppie imagen recortada es incorrecta

Tags: html, jquery, imagen, bootstrap

He montado para una pequeña biblioteca de recetas de cocina con un gestor de imagenes realizado con croopie.

[croopie](https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/)

El  script carga la imagen, la re dimensiona y la recorta pero el problema, cuando giro la imagen y la fijo, es que recorta demasiado y deja en negro una zona de la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Os dejo un ejemplo a ver si podéis descubrir donde fallo, por que ya le he dado demasiadas vueltas y seguro que ya no lo veo. [ejemplo funcionado](https://jsfiddle.net/Spocky/spd7axzv/20/)

El script está con boostrap4 y jquery 3.4.1

tiene un límite de 5 imágenes para subir, que se configura en el propio js

Al cargar y aplicar la redimensión y recorte de cada imagen se pone en una fila de una tabla ya recortada.

la imagen a exportar toma sus dimensiones de una variables .

```
  var anchoExport = 900;
var altoExport = 500;
```

croppie, en sus valores de ancho y alto para el visor de imagen toma el ancho de del div que lo contiene y procesa los valores necesarios para que sea "responsive" (no real por que no cambia al cambiar el tamaño de la ventana pero por ahora me vale.

```
var boundaryW = $("#visor").width();
```

por regla de tres obtengo el alto

```
var boundaryH = (altoExport * boundaryW) / anchoExport;
```

hay mas variables para determinar que sea jpg, el tamaño, la zona de recorte...
y oculta y muestra elementos dependiendo del paso en el que esté, subir, aceptar, borrar...

Este es el script funcionando:

```js
 var num = 0; // el contador de filas comienza en 1
    var max = 5; // controla el numero maximo de filas

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#maximg").html('' + max + '');
    });


    $(document).on('click', '.image-cancel', function() {
        let no = $(this).data('no');
        $(".preview-image.preview-show-" + no).remove();

        max = max + 1; //controla el maximo de items

        verificaMaximo(max)


    });


    var anchoExport = 900;
    var altoExport = 500;

    var boundaryW = $("#visor").width();
    
    var boundaryH = (altoExport * boundaryW) / anchoExport;

    var viewportW = boundaryW - 100;
    var viewportH = (boundaryH * viewportW) / boundaryW;

    var maxUploadSize = "4194304";//  en bytes
    var maxUploadSizeMB = ((maxUploadSize / 1024)/1024)




    function verificaMaximo(max) {
        $("#maximg").html('' + max + ''); //coloca el numero de imagenes en el titulo
        if (max <= 0) { // verifica si se ha alcanzado el limite
            $('#previewImage').addClass("d-none"); // oculta preview
            $('.btn-upload-image').addClass("d-none");
            $('.rowPrevisualizar').addClass("d-none");
           

        } else {
            $('#previewImage').removeClass("d-none"); // muestra preview
            $('.btn-upload-image').removeClass("d-none");
            $('.rowPrevisualizar').removeClass("d-none");
        }
    }




    var resize = $('#previewImage').croppie({
        url: 'recipe-default.png',
        enableExif: false,
        enableOrientation: true,
        viewport: { // Default { width: 100, height: 100, type: 'square' } 
            width: viewportW,
            height: viewportH,
            type: 'square' //square - circle
        },
        boundary: {
            width: boundaryW,
            height: boundaryH
        }
    });




    // Al cambiar el campos de archivo
    $('.usrSelectImage').on('change', function() {
        
        //tomamos el indice 0 del atributo image por que es una unica imagen


        var usrSelectImage = this.files[0];

        if (usrSelectImage['type'] != 'image/jpeg') {
            //ponemos a 0 el campo file
            $('.usrSelectImage').val(null);

            //alerta suave
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'Oops...',
                text: '!Sólo se permiten imágenes jpg¡',
                timer: 6500
            });
            //verificamos que sea menos de maxUploadSize (mb = 1048576 bytes)
        } else if (usrSelectImage['size'] > maxUploadSize) {

            $('.usrSelectImage').val(null);

            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'Oops...',
                text: '!El tamaño de la imagen no debe pesar más de '+maxUploadSizeMB+' mb¡',
                timer: 6500
            });
        } else {

            $('.btn-upload-image').addClass("d-none");
            $('.btn-rotate-left').removeClass("d-none");
            $('.btn-rotate-right').removeClass("d-none");
            $('.btn-aplicar-image').removeClass("d-none");
            $('.btn-borrar-image').removeClass("d-none");

            $('#visor').removeClass("d-none");
            $('.rowPrevisualizar').addClass("d-none");

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                resize.croppie('bind', {
                    url: e.target.result
                }).then(function() {

                    // console.log('jQuery bind complete');

                });
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(usrSelectImage);


        }


    });






    $('.btn-aplicar-image').on('click', function(ev) {
        resize.croppie('result', {
            circle: false,

            // size: 'viewport',
            size: {
                width: anchoExport,
                height: altoExport
            },
            type: 'base64',
            format: 'jpeg',
        }).then(function(img) {
            var rutaImagen = event.target.result;
            $('#visor').addClass("d-none");
            $('.btn-rotate-left').addClass("d-none");
            $('.btn-rotate-right').addClass("d-none");
            $('.btn-aplicar-image').addClass("d-none");
            $('.btn-borrar-image').addClass("d-none");
            $('.btn-upload-image').removeClass("d-none");






            var html = '<tr class="preview-image preview-show-' + num + '">' +
                '<td>' +
                '<img id="pro-img-' + num + '" src="' + img + '" width="100px">' +
                '<input id="image' + num + '" name="image' + num + '" class="d-none" type="text" value="' + img + '">' +
                '</td>' +
                '<td><div class="image-cancel btn btn-danger" data-no="' + num + '"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></div></td>' +
                '</tr>';

            $('.preview-images-zone').append(html);


            num++;
            max--;

            verificaMaximo(max);


            //


            /////////////////// reinica el visor

            $('#previewImage').croppie('destroy');

            var resize = $('#previewImage').croppie({
                url: 'recipe-default.png',
                enableExif: false,
                enableOrientation: true,
                viewport: { // Default { width: 100, height: 100, type: 'square' } 
                    width: viewportW,
                    height: viewportH,
                    type: 'square' //square - circle
                },
                boundary: {
                    width: boundaryW,
                    height: boundaryH
                }
            });

            /////////////////// reincia el visor




        });
    });

    $('.btn-borrar-image').on('click', function() {

        $('.previsualizar').attr('src', 'recipe-default.png');
        $('.usrSelectImage').val(null);
        $('#visor').addClass("d-none");
        $('.rowPrevisualizar').addClass("d-none");
        $('.btn-rotate-left').addClass("d-none");
        $('.btn-rotate-right').addClass("d-none");
        $('.btn-upload-image').removeClass("d-none");
        $('.btn-aplicar-image').addClass("d-none");
        $('.btn-borrar-image').addClass("d-none");
        //$('#usrImage').val('null');

        //$( "#usrImage" ).remove();

        verificaMaximo(max);


        $('#previewImage').croppie('destroy');

        var resize = $('#previewImage').croppie({
            url: 'recipe-default.png',
            enableExif: false,
            enableOrientation: true,
            viewport: { // Default { width: 100, height: 100, type: 'square' } 
                    width: viewportW,
                    height: viewportH,
                 type: 'square' //square - circle
            },
            boundary: {
                width: boundaryW,
                height: boundaryH
            }
        });


    });

    //rotar
    $(".btn-rotate-right").click(function() {
        $('#previewImage').croppie('rotate', parseInt($(this).data('rotate')));
    });

    $(".btn-rotate-left").click(function() {
        $('#previewImage').croppie('rotate', parseInt($(this).data('rotate')));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.1/css/all.min.css">



<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>




<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Tooltip App -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/offerdocker/vistas/plugins/sweetalert2/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/croppie/2.6.4/croppie.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/croppie/2.6.4/croppie.js"></script>

<!-- Content Header (Page header) -->




<!-- Main content -->
<section class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">



            <div class="col-md-12">



                <div class="row">
                    <!-- left column -->
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <!-- general form elements -->
                        <div class="card card-primary">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <h3 class="card-title">Gestor de imagen</h3>
                            </div>


                            <div class="card-body">






                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <div class="row">

                                        <div class="col-sm-12" id="visor">
                                            <input type="file" id="usrSelectImage" class="usrSelectImage d-none">

                                            <div id="previewImage"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <div class="row rowPrevisualizar d-none">

                                                <img class="previsualizar product-image" src="recipe-default.png" alt="" width="100%">
                                                <p>&nbsp;</p><br>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="row">





                                                <label for="usrSelectImage" class="btn btn-app text-primary btn-upload-image"><i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i> Subir archivo</label>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-app btn-aplicar-image text-success d-none"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Aplicar</button>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-app btn-borrar-image text-danger d-none"><i class="fas fa-times"></i> Borrar </button>
                                                <button type="button" data-rotate="-90" class="btn btn-app text-info btn-rotate-left d-none"><i class="fas fa-undo-alt"></i>&nbsp;Izquierda </button>
                                                <button type="button" data-rotate="90" class="btn btn-app text-info btn-rotate-right d-none"><i class="fas fa-redo-alt"></i>&nbsp;Izquierda </button>


                                                <!-- </div> -->






                                            </div>






                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                </div>
                            </div>


                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- right column -->
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <!-- general form elements -->
                        <div class="card card-primary">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <h3 class="card-title"><span id="maximg"></span> Imágenes disponibles</h3>
                            </div>

                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="row">


                                    <style>
                                        .preview-images-zone {
                                            width: 100%;
                                            border: 1px solid #ddd;
                                        }

                                        .preview-images-zone>.preview-image {
                                            border: 1px solid #ddd;
                                        }
                                    </style>




                                    <table style="width:100%">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th></th>
                                            <th></th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tbody class="preview-images-zone">

                                        </tbody>

                                    </table>



                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>



            <!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</section>
<!-- /.content -->
```

También está en [jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/Spocky/spd7axzv/20/) Mil gracias a todos/as

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer, el fallo no es mío...es de la version 2.6.4 de croppie

alguien lo ha arreglado y funciona con este js en vez del original

https://static.qmsystems.de/js/lib/croppie.js

Os lo dejo funcionando por si a alguno le vale en el futuro

```js
 var num = 0; // el contador de filas comienza en 1
    var max = 5; // controla el numero maximo de filas

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#maximg").html('' + max + '');
    });


    $(document).on('click', '.image-cancel', function() {
        let no = $(this).data('no');
        $(".preview-image.preview-show-" + no).remove();

        max = max + 1; //controla el maximo de items

        verificaMaximo(max)


    });


    var anchoExport = 900;
    var altoExport = 500;

    var boundaryW = $("#visor").width();
    
    var boundaryH = (altoExport * boundaryW) / anchoExport;

    var viewportW = boundaryW - 100;
    var viewportH = (boundaryH * viewportW) / boundaryW;

    var maxUploadSize = "4194304";//  en bytes
    var maxUploadSizeMB = ((maxUploadSize / 1024)/1024)




    function verificaMaximo(max) {
        $("#maximg").html('' + max + ''); //coloca el numero de imagenes en el titulo
        if (max <= 0) { // verifica si se ha alcanzado el limite
            $('#previewImage').addClass("d-none"); // oculta preview
            $('.btn-upload-image').addClass("d-none");
            $('.rowPrevisualizar').addClass("d-none");
           

        } else {
            $('#previewImage').removeClass("d-none"); // muestra preview
            $('.btn-upload-image').removeClass("d-none");
            $('.rowPrevisualizar').removeClass("d-none");
        }
    }




    var resize = $('#previewImage').croppie({
        url: 'recipe-default.png',
        enableExif: false,
        enableOrientation: true,
        viewport: { // Default { width: 100, height: 100, type: 'square' } 
            width: viewportW,
            height: viewportH,
            type: 'square' //square - circle
        },
        boundary: {
            width: boundaryW,
            height: boundaryH
        }
    });




    // Al cambiar el campos de archivo
    $('.usrSelectImage').on('change', function() {
        
        //tomamos el indice 0 del atributo image por que es una unica imagen


        var usrSelectImage = this.files[0];

        if (usrSelectImage['type'] != 'image/jpeg') {
            //ponemos a 0 el campo file
            $('.usrSelectImage').val(null);

            //alerta suave
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'Oops...',
                text: '!Sólo se permiten imágenes jpg¡',
                timer: 6500
            });
            //verificamos que sea menos de maxUploadSize (mb = 1048576 bytes)
        } else if (usrSelectImage['size'] > maxUploadSize) {

            $('.usrSelectImage').val(null);

            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'Oops...',
                text: '!El tamaño de la imagen no debe pesar más de '+maxUploadSizeMB+' mb¡',
                timer: 6500
            });
        } else {

            $('.btn-upload-image').addClass("d-none");
            $('.btn-rotate-left').removeClass("d-none");
            $('.btn-rotate-right').removeClass("d-none");
            $('.btn-aplicar-image').removeClass("d-none");
            $('.btn-borrar-image').removeClass("d-none");

            $('#visor').removeClass("d-none");
            $('.rowPrevisualizar').addClass("d-none");

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                resize.croppie('bind', {
                    url: e.target.result
                }).then(function() {

                    // console.log('jQuery bind complete');

                });
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(usrSelectImage);


        }


    });






    $('.btn-aplicar-image').on('click', function(ev) {
        resize.croppie('result', {
            circle: false,

            // size: 'viewport',
            size: {
                width: anchoExport,
                height: altoExport
            },
            type: 'base64',
            format: 'jpeg',
        }).then(function(img) {
            var rutaImagen = event.target.result;
            $('#visor').addClass("d-none");
            $('.btn-rotate-left').addClass("d-none");
            $('.btn-rotate-right').addClass("d-none");
            $('.btn-aplicar-image').addClass("d-none");
            $('.btn-borrar-image').addClass("d-none");
            $('.btn-upload-image').removeClass("d-none");






            var html = '<tr class="preview-image preview-show-' + num + '">' +
                '<td>' +
                '<img id="pro-img-' + num + '" src="' + img + '" width="100px">' +
                '<input id="image' + num + '" name="image' + num + '" class="d-none" type="text" value="' + img + '">' +
                '</td>' +
                '<td><div class="image-cancel btn btn-danger" data-no="' + num + '"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></div></td>' +
                '</tr>';

            $('.preview-images-zone').append(html);


            num++;
            max--;

            verificaMaximo(max);


            //


            /////////////////// reinica el visor

            $('#previewImage').croppie('destroy');

            var resize = $('#previewImage').croppie({
                url: 'recipe-default.png',
                enableExif: false,
                enableOrientation: true,
                viewport: { // Default { width: 100, height: 100, type: 'square' } 
                    width: viewportW,
                    height: viewportH,
                    type: 'square' //square - circle
                },
                boundary: {
                    width: boundaryW,
                    height: boundaryH
                }
            });

            /////////////////// reincia el visor




        });
    });

    $('.btn-borrar-image').on('click', function() {

        $('.previsualizar').attr('src', 'recipe-default.png');
        $('.usrSelectImage').val(null);
        $('#visor').addClass("d-none");
        $('.rowPrevisualizar').addClass("d-none");
        $('.btn-rotate-left').addClass("d-none");
        $('.btn-rotate-right').addClass("d-none");
        $('.btn-upload-image').removeClass("d-none");
        $('.btn-aplicar-image').addClass("d-none");
        $('.btn-borrar-image').addClass("d-none");
        //$('#usrImage').val('null');

        //$( "#usrImage" ).remove();

        verificaMaximo(max);


        $('#previewImage').croppie('destroy');

        var resize = $('#previewImage').croppie({
            url: 'recipe-default.png',
            enableExif: false,
            enableOrientation: true,
            viewport: { // Default { width: 100, height: 100, type: 'square' } 
                    width: viewportW,
                    height: viewportH,
                 type: 'square' //square - circle
            },
            boundary: {
                width: boundaryW,
                height: boundaryH
            }
        });


    });

    //rotar
    $(".btn-rotate-right").click(function() {
        $('#previewImage').croppie('rotate', parseInt($(this).data('rotate')));
    });

    $(".btn-rotate-left").click(function() {
        $('#previewImage').croppie('rotate', parseInt($(this).data('rotate')));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.1/css/all.min.css">



<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>




<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Tooltip App -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/offerdocker/vistas/plugins/sweetalert2/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/croppie/2.6.4/croppie.min.css">
<script src="https://static.qmsystems.de/js/lib/croppie.js"></script>

<!-- Content Header (Page header) -->




<!-- Main content -->
<section class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">



            <div class="col-md-12">



                <div class="row">
                    <!-- left column -->
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <!-- general form elements -->
                        <div class="card card-primary">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <h3 class="card-title">Gestor de imagen</h3>
                            </div>


                            <div class="card-body">






                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <div class="row">

                                        <div class="col-sm-12" id="visor">
                                            <input type="file" id="usrSelectImage" class="usrSelectImage d-none">

                                            <div id="previewImage"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <div class="row rowPrevisualizar d-none">

                                                <img class="previsualizar product-image" src="recipe-default.png" alt="" width="100%">
                                                <p>&nbsp;</p><br>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="row">





                                                <label for="usrSelectImage" class="btn btn-app text-primary btn-upload-image"><i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i> Subir archivo</label>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-app btn-aplicar-image text-success d-none"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Aplicar</button>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-app btn-borrar-image text-danger d-none"><i class="fas fa-times"></i> Borrar </button>
                                                <button type="button" data-rotate="-90" class="btn btn-app text-info btn-rotate-left d-none"><i class="fas fa-undo-alt"></i>&nbsp;Izquierda </button>
                                                <button type="button" data-rotate="90" class="btn btn-app text-info btn-rotate-right d-none"><i class="fas fa-redo-alt"></i>&nbsp;Izquierda </button>


                                                <!-- </div> -->






                                            </div>






                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                </div>
                            </div>


                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- right column -->
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <!-- general form elements -->
                        <div class="card card-primary">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <h3 class="card-title"><span id="maximg"></span> Imágenes disponibles</h3>
                            </div>

                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="row">


                                    <style>
                                        .preview-images-zone {
                                            width: 100%;
                                            border: 1px solid #ddd;
                                        }

                                        .preview-images-zone>.preview-image {
                                            border: 1px solid #ddd;
                                        }
                                    </style>




                                    <table style="width:100%">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th></th>
                                            <th></th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tbody class="preview-images-zone">

                                        </tbody>

                                    </table>



                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>



            <!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</section>
<!-- /.content -->
```

Comment: En mi caso me tuve que bajar a la versión 2.6.3